# Set prefix in SQL CASE expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I have problem setting a prefix in a case statement.

Data set:

```
missionid:
5505
5506


select
CASE
WHEN m.EXTLOCATIONID is not null THEN '01' + convert(nvarchar(50),m.missionid) 
ELSE tg.ID_ACTIVITY
END as Barcode2
from MISSION m
left join TASKGROUP tg with(nolock) on m.MMPICKLISTID = tg.ID
```

When I run this query my result is this:

```
Barcode2: 
15505
15506
```

Desired result is this:

```
015505
015506
```

As one can see, the first zero is not shown in the result. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is there any special reason you used `NO Lock` ?

Comment: case *expression* not *statement*

Comment: Fixed my title.we use the NoLock since this query is used for a label print

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CASE` expression would always return one type so, you need to do conversion:

```
CASE WHEN m.EXTLOCATIONID is not null 
     THEN '01' + convert(nvarchar(50), m.missionid) 
     ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), tg.ID_ACTIVITY)
END as Barcode2
```

Answer (score 1):

A `case` expression returns a single type.  And, if different paths return different types -- say a string and a number -- then the result is a number.  Those are the rules of SQL.

You are also mixing national character sets with "regular" characters.  That seems unnecessary.  I would recommend:

```
(CASE WHEN m.EXTLOCATIONID is not null 
      THEN CONCAT('01', m.missionid) 
      ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), tg.ID_ACTIVITY)
 END) as Barcode2
```